# Consolibyte Quickbooks Integration General Question

Tags: php, quickbooks

I've taken Consolibyte's  2.0.0 STABLE RELEASE – QuickBooks PHP DevKit v2.0.0 download and uploaded the example .qwc file to qb web connector in my sample workbook. I am running XXAMP local host. I'm trying to connect the web connector but it comes back "authentication falled and returns this error:

Message:
Authentication failed

### Description:
QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message.
Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', but expected 'text/xml'.
The request failed with the error message:

**Fatal error**:  Redefinition of parameter $action in **C:\xampp\htdocs\quickbooks-devkit\build\build_20130416\QuickBooks\Callbacks.php** on line **587**

--. See QWCLog for more details. Remember to turn logging on.

MY .QWC file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <QBWCXML>
         <AppName>QuickBooks Integrator</AppName>
         <AppID></AppID>
         <AppURL>http://localhost/quickbooks- 
       devkit/build/build_20130416/docs/example_web_connector.php</AppURL>
         <AppDescription></AppDescription>
         <AppSupport>http://localhost</AppSupport>
         <UserName>quickbooks</UserName>
         <OwnerID>{90A44FB7-33D9-4815-AC85-AC86A7E7D1EB}</OwnerID>
         <FileID>{57F3B9B6-86F1-4fcc-B1FF-967DE1813D20}</FileID>
         <QBType>QBFS</QBType>
         <Scheduler>
         <RunEveryNMinutes>1</RunEveryNMinutes>
         </Scheduler>
         <IsReadOnly>false</IsReadOnly>
 </QBWCXML>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've also created a soap project with the consolibyte WSDL using soap UI

Not what you wanted to do ^^^. Also, we don't provide a `.wsdl` (maybe you're talking about the one that *Intuit* provides?) so I'm not real clear what you're doing here... but for sure it isn't right.

> I need help on the steps thereafter

Follow the quick-start guide:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php#quick-start-guides

> I have worked with PHP and Apache servers, but SOAP is new.

You should need almost zero knowledge of SOAP to get this working. It sounds like you're just not following the quick-start, which is *mandatory*.

Follow the quick-start guide. If you get stuck, *post your code* so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: Where do i find my SQL connection string for my Quickbooks? i've been looking online and i haven't been able to find any information. Is "Know your MySQL connection string, you'll use it later, it should look like below." referring to the database information on my server?

Comment: After further research in the quickstart guide I have found various examples of an SQL connection, username, password, db string, and then a path to my quickbooks SOAP server. I'm not sure where to find this information. I have soap UI downloaded onto my computer so it's not connected to my server, nor quickbooks at the moment

Comment: `SOAP UI` is not relevant in any way, I don't know why you're using that. If you're using MySQL, then your connection string is: `mysqli://your-mysql-username:your-mysql_password@your-mysql-server-hostname:3306/your-mysql-database-name`  If you don't know your MySQL username/password/etc., then you should contact your web host to get that information.

Comment: I am now using Tomcat and I have to deploy the php devkit to tomcat, I was wondering how i go about doing this? i know i need to change my app URL and App support to match the new location on the soap server.

Comment: And which file in the php devkit returns a 200 OK for the appsupport?

Comment: You can't run PHP directly in Tomcat. You'd need a WAR that embeds/re-impelements PHP or proxies PHP somehow... It sounds like you're making things very difficult for yourself...

Comment: No where in your guides does it suggest anything about setting  up a soap server, all of this information is implied. Could you please point me in a direction to set this up?

Comment: You do not need to set up a SOAP server... the code _is_ the SOAP server. 

Are you following this quick-start guide? http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Quick-Start

Comment: Yeah I am, I was over thinking it, I believe this is much simpler than i was making it. I have a 404 not found error in my web connector and "authentication failed".

Comment: If you're following the quick-start guide, then please: 1. tell us what step you're on and 2. post the Web Connector logs (click the VIEW LOG) button and 3. post your code and 4. post your .QWC file

Comment: Description:
QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message.
Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', but expected 'text/xml'.
The request failed with the error message:
--
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Redefinition of parameter $action in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\quickbooks-devkit\build\build_20130416\QuickBooks\Callbacks.php</b> on line <b>587</b><br />

This is my error